# Why cant we do arithmetic operations on structs in C?

Tags: c

```
struct a{
int a;
char b;
} c,d={1,2},e;

c=d //allowed
c=d+e  //not allowed
```

Assignment works, as compiler generates the assembly code to move the bytes.
so same thing can be done for other operators.
So why doesnt C have this feature??

<===========>

As asked, Some of the features can be..
1. While adding large number(more than long's) we dont have to use the loop to add it long by long.

c=a+b

will work.

1. Shifting the arrays.
2. multiplication.

so we dont have to write the extra code, for these things compiler can generate the assembly code.

Comment: Because there is no chance of implementing it in a way that would please everybody.

Comment: I always cringe when someone asks a question like *"Why doesn't [programming language] have [feature]?"* What kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: I am expecting just an explanation. And i am sure if question is not proper then there should be some explanation for it.

Answer (score 11):

Because in C there's no way to tell the compiler what the expected result would be. For example, how would you add 2 objects like this:

```
struct ss {
    char *str;
};
```

Comment: I agree. But i was thinking if we can get just the binary addition.
So adding to char pointers won't make any sense but in many other places we can use the operations.
<ok instead of writing here i update the question itself>

Answer (score 3):

Because you can't define arithmetic operation on structs. They are not numbers, nor strings, nor floats, nor whatever calculable. If your struct is a list of some personal data like :

```
struct person {
  int age;
  char name[200];
  int zipcode;
  int sex;
  whatever_t whatever;
} Mary, Ivan;
```

How can you define Mary + Ivan then ?

EDIT:

If you want to make addition of the bits underneath you could create an array of char and then memcpy inside it

```
int size = sizeof (struct person); 
char arr[size];
memcpy(arr, &person, size);
```

And then add the bits inside with another struct that you cast the same way.

Comment: Semantically, the algebra of {Male,Female} or zipcodes with + is highly questionable, but since in C you can add char a='a'; char b='b'; char z=a+b; there is no reason why above example couldn't be translated. It would be up to programmer responsibility to know if + makes sense or not... The sole illegal op is adding pointers. In languages with higher reflection capabilities (Smalltalk), you could iterate on struct fields and define a generic addition. The main cost would be to hide programming errors which is the best reason to avoid such generic construct...

Comment: @Dimitar
as you said structs aren't float ,char,ints but they are sequence of bits. And i wanted to do the operations on these bits.

And thnks for quick rply :)

Comment: @aka.nice raju abhinav My point is that there is no logic in having arithmetic on structs. Well at least no more then having bit shift on floats. If you want to make some magic with the bits underneath you have to make some hackery. I think you could create an array of chars and then memcpy the struct in it and you will have the bits in more raw form and then you could define your addition and so. But having a standard + operator will probably be just an invitation for silly bugs 99.9% of the time.

Comment: @DimitarSlavchev 100% agree your last sentence which is just a clearer reformulation of my last sentence and is a very good reason why we do not implement such generic +, even if we can (Smalltalk).

Comment: @DimitarSlavchev yeah but we can have +, -, * ,/ and so on for which we dont have to write the code on byte level (as you suggested) as i have added in question. 
And can you give some examples how + operator will invite silly bugs?

Comment: @raju abhinav Well, if you have that + operator on the example I gave. And that + operator is defined as ... lets say + on all members. The result will be totally meaningless (zip code + zop code = ???) without any warning.

Comment: @DimitarSlavchev My point is if we can access as many bytes as we want using structs in c, why shouldn't we use it directly for other operations...
And your zip+zop is still not clear, please clarify bit more if possible.

Comment: @raju abhinav I was saying that struct is not a clearly defined type. It is user defined and is made to be flexible and if your algorithm needs a struct addition it will be a user defined struct addition. You can't have it built in (it is user defined), and you don't have operator overloading to redefine it so you have no reason to have built in struct addition. Yet the bytes are still there and if you want to have some addition on them you should write your own function. Otherwise you will have a built in + operator that is useless 99.9% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can. We should use just another technique.

As cnicutar sad why we can not tell C compiler how to use uperator `+` for structs. The base line is that complie do not know what result shold be from such operation. Out there exists languages that support operator overloading (C++/C#), but for this case we can must use some desing aproach as C is not one of them so we must crate method for that operation.

So instead of `c = d + e` we can write `MyStructMath_add(d,e)`.

And implement by yourself the the logic what you expect for such operation.

Comment: A better way to do that would be to overload the `+` operator.

Comment: You both are aware that this question is tagged "C", not "C++"? C doesn't have methods and operator overloading.

Comment: @Secure, oops with that dot. Fixed for static call.

Comment: @Josh Petitt, correted. Thanks for pointing that out.